# List validation one by one

Tags: python, list

I know this is a very simple question but I would like to know how to check each index from the list or 1 by 1, from starting to ending of the index. without using lambda just a simple for loop.

```
List = ['a','b','c']
required = 'c'
```

output:

```
>>False
>>False
>>True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def test(check):
    try:
        for i in L:
            if i == check:
                print 'True'
            else:
                print 'False'
            # print cmp(i,check)
    except:
        pass
test('c')
```

very basic..:)

Comment: The if/else with prints can be even more succinctly expressed as `print i == check`; no need for a call to `cmp` (which would return -1, 0 or 1, and has been deprecated in python for ages, removed in Py3).